# Do we have to specify actions by many elements when defining some semidirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, semidirect-product

When studying about the semidirect product, $G=(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)\rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z}_q$, I understood that, for some semidirect products by considering a minimal generating set $S=\{s,t\}$, where $|s|=q, |t|=p$, an action of $s$ on $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ can be defined.

For $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_q \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$, let $\phi(s)=\phi_s$. Then, $\phi_s(v) = s^{-1}vs$, $v \in \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ (action of $s$). This defines the semidirect product.

When considering a group like, $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)\rtimes_h (\mathbb{Z}_q \times \mathbb{Z}_q)$, let $h:(\mathbb{Z}_q \times \mathbb{Z}_q) \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$. Then can there be instances where we have to mention two actions by two generating elements, say $s_1,s_2 \in (\mathbb{Z}_q \times \mathbb{Z}_q)$ of order $q$, to define $h$? (i.e. to define the semidirect product)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes, a homomorphism $h:\Bbb Z_q^2\to{\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_p^2)$ sends two generators of $\Bbb Z_q^2$ to two commuting elements of ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_p^2)$, and conversely $h$ is determined by those two elements. This doesn't really have much to do with semidirect products specifically, it's just a question about homomorphisms and generating sets. In general, any group homomorphism sends a generating set to another set of elements satisfying the same defining relations (in this case, commuting and $q$-powering to the identity), and is also determined by this.

Comment: Thank you very much @runway44